# Most recent records sybase return incomplete table (toad 2.0)

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I have tested on sqlfiddle and it should work...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74041/4

Table fields

```
row id_ (numeric) action (int) paymentDate (datetime) updateDate (datetime)
1   56            1            12/23/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/3/2014 3:21:50 PM
2   56            1            12/24/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/3/2014 3:21:50 PM
3   56            1            12/25/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/3/2014 3:21:50 PM
4   56            1            12/26/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/3/2014 3:21:50 PM
5   56            1            12/27/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/3/2014 3:21:50 PM
6   56            1            12/23/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM
7   56            1            12/24/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM
8   56            1            12/25/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM
9   56            1            12/26/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM
10  56            1            12/27/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM

Results expected

6   56            1            12/23/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM
7   56            1            12/24/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM
8   56            1            12/25/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM
9   56            1            12/26/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM
10  56            1            12/27/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM

Results obtained

9   56            1            12/26/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM
10  56            1            12/27/2015 10:59:00 AM 12/4/2014 3:21:50 PM

Query (sybase)

select * from table where id = 56 and actionType = 1 and updateDate = (SELECT max(updateDate) from table) group by updateDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the updateDate was actually a field set by directly inserting the getDate(). There was a difference not observable, so I passed instead the value getDate() to a datetime variable. Fixed the issue.